# How different are the manga, anime and movie versions of Ajin?

Tags: ajin-demi-human

Ajin is originally [a manga](http://myanimelist.net/manga/49865/Ajin), that has subsequently had a few adaptations into anime. In November 2015, it seems to have been adapted into a movie: [Ajin Part 1: Shoudou (Ajin: Demi-Human - Compel)](http://myanimelist.net/anime/30868/Ajin_Part_1__Shoudou). MAL's blurb for the movie reads:

> For high schooler Kei—and for at least forty-six others—immortality comes as the nastiest surprise ever.
>
> Sadly for Kei, such a feat doesn't make him a superhero. In the eyes of both the general public and governments, he's a rare specimen who needs to be hunted down and handed over to scientists to be experimented on for life—a demi-human who must die a thousand deaths for the benefit of humanity.

The movie lists two yet unreleased sequels: [Ajin Part 2: Shoutotsu](http://myanimelist.net/anime/30869/Ajin_Part_2__Shoutotsu), set to be released in May 2016; and [Ajin Part 3: Shougeki](http://myanimelist.net/anime/30870/Ajin_Part_3__Shougeki), set to be released in Seprember 2016. The blurb for these two is the same as the one for the first movie.

The manga was also adapted into an anime series, [Ajin](http://myanimelist.net/anime/31580/Ajin), released between January and April 2016 (the Winter 2016 season). This one lists the three movies as "Alternative versions", and its blurb reads:

> Where there is life, there is death... or is there? What would you do if you could never die? The possibilities are endless.
>
> Seventeen years ago, the existence of a special species called Ajin was discovered in Africa. They are said to be immortal beings, with several supernatural abilities, that look just like any other human being. Are these Ajin just random phenomena of nature or were they purposely sent to Earth to destroy it?
>
> Since their first discovery, several other Ajin appearances have been reported worldwide. For the majority of citizens though, these creatures are less reality and more of something you see every once in a while in a textbook or on the news. This is how it was for the young protagonist of the series, Kei. That was until a sudden turn of events changed his life forever...
>
> Ajin is a supernatural anime full of complex ideas about life and death, as well as the dark side of human nature. What does it mean to truly be human?

It's not entirely clear to me whether the first movie covers the anime series and the other two are new content, or whether the three movies are supposed to be recaps of the whole series (maybe there are supposed to be three anime seasons of Ajin, and each of the movies recaps one of them?).

What's the relation between the manga, the anime series, and the movies (given that two of the three movies haven't been released yet, that part may be harder to answer)? Are the adaptations faithful to the manga?

Comment: Having seen the first movie and first season of the series, I can confirm that the series cover all of the first movie, using the exact same scenes, and some more. I remember it surprising me because I didn't expect the series to cover more than the first movie when the second one was just released in theaters not so long ago comparatively. I didn't see the second movie or the second season of the series, though, so I cannot say if the end of the first season is different from the second movie or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have watched the anime until the very last episode so far, which is the 8th of the second season, while I also keep on reading the manga (it is still on going). First season of Ajin is totally faithful to the manga until the last two episodes, then it just changes a little so it is not a big deal. But this second season is, from the 2 episode and on, super different from the manga. Now, this does not mean anime is not as good as the manga, this second season is very nice indeed, but what happens is that in the manga there were some really interesting parts involving important character backstory. For example,

> Izumi's which was very crude and harrowing but it seems like in the anime they have censored it, which really pissed me off. Then we got Kei Nagai's true feelings towards what is going on around him, which is not clearly shown in anime, and also and the most different thing: they have changed all the main plot.

Everything that happens in the manga that should have been in this second season is not there, the fights, the crazy af plans of Satou, etc. This, however, could be explained because I believe the second season started when this amazing arc in the manga was not over yet, so I guess production decided to just walk the FMA path. But as I said, it is still worth watching it, it is good and adds new stuff:

> we can see some development in Izumi and Tosaki's relationship and we kinda get 1 minute or less of fanservice with cute Nagai blushing.

So yeah basically, first season is completely faithful, second season is not but it still very good.